# selection of only one radio button in C#

Tags: c#

i am a beginner in windows form application. 
i am maintaining student record.
the problem is that when i checked Male or female button , in sql database both female and male show in gender column , not only one. 
please help me.
here is my code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    coachingdbDataContext coach = new coachingdbDataContext();
    std_table std = new std_table()
    {
        Name= nametxt.Text,
        Father_Name= fnametxt.Text,
        Class= classtxt.Text,
        Roll_Number= rolltxt.Text,
        Address=addresstxt.Text,
        Contact_Number=numtxt.Text,
        Date_Of_Birth=daybox.Text +" "+ monthbox.Text +" "+ yearbox.Text,
        Gender= malebutton.Text + femalebutton.Text,
    };

    coach.std_tables.InsertOnSubmit(std);  
    coach.SubmitChanges();
    MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Submitted");                       
}
```

Comment: Why you are doing it like this - `Gender= malebutton.Text + femalebutton.Text,`

Answer (score 5):

You'll have to check for `Checked` radio button:

```
Gender = malebutton.Checked == true ? malebutton.Text : femalebutton.Text;
```

Comment: Thanks alot i don't know the use of '?' mark for selection. thanks

Comment: The `?:` operator is the terniary operator, and it's a shortcut for the if/else statement.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a likely culprit:

```
Gender = malebutton.Text + femalebutton.Text
```

Regardless of which button is selected, both of the buttons *have* text.  So both will be inserted.

You probably want to check which one is selected.  What are the types of `malebutton` and `femalebutton`?  Do they, for example, have a `Checked` property?  Something like this might work then:

```
Gender = malebutton.Checked ? malebutton.Text :
         (femalebutton.Checked ? femalebutton.Text :
         "unspecified");
```

If the male button is checked, us that text.  Else, if the female button is checked, use that text.  Else, use a default value.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the text from both together then of course you get both in our output.

```
Gender= malebutton.Text + femalebutton.Text
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Use this:

```
    std_table std = new std_table()
    {
        Name= nametxt.Text,
        Father_Name= fnametxt.Text,
        Class= classtxt.Text,
        Roll_Number= rolltxt.Text,
        Address=addresstxt.Text,
        Contact_Number=numtxt.Text,
        Date_Of_Birth=daybox.Text +" "+ monthbox.Text +" "+ yearbox.Text,
        Gender=  malebutton.Checked ? malebutton.Text : femalebutton.Text;
    };
```

You can read about the `?` operator [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx).

Comment: yeah now it has been done. Thanks alot i don't know the use of '?' mark for selection. thanks

Comment: That is not necessarily needed, but it is very useful for inline conditionals. I posted a link to a page that can tell you more about that operation.

Comment: oh thanks a lot. using 1st time this site, and i m very happy, helpful

Answer (score 0):

This is the culprit:

```
Gender= malebutton.Text + femalebutton.Text,
```

Do this instead:

```
std_table std = new std_table()
{
    Name= nametxt.Text,
    Father_Name= fnametxt.Text,
    Class= classtxt.Text,
    Roll_Number= rolltxt.Text,
    Address=addresstxt.Text,
    Contact_Number=numtxt.Text,
    Date_Of_Birth=daybox.Text +" "+ monthbox.Text +" "+ yearbox.Text
};

if ( malebutton.Checked ) { 
    std.Gender = malebutton.Text;
}

if (femalebutton.Checked ) { 
    std.Gender = femalebutton.Text;
}
```

Comment: It was meant to? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: you suggest right, i just said your answer is different from others.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Yes, I intentionally used more basic constructs in hopes it would be easier to understand. But all the answers I have seen are good answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the

```
Gender= malebutton.Text + femalebutton.Text
```

by

```
if(malebutton.checked == true ) 
{
Gender= malebutton.Text;
}
else
{
Gender= femalebutton.Text;
}
```

hopefully this will solve your problem

Comment: no, i can't use gender multiple time, i have tried this. thanks for suggestion